# A question about the functoriality of the module of derivations on the category of algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, differential-forms, diagram-chasing

Assume that all rings are commutative with identity. Let $k$ be a fixed ring with $k$-algebras $\varphi: k \rightarrow R$ and $\tau: k \rightarrow A$. Let $\tau' : R \rightarrow B$ define an $R$-algebra and $\psi: A \rightarrow B$ a morphism of rings so that the square commutes, that is
$$
\tau' \varphi = \psi \tau.
$$
Suppose further that $\psi: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective. Let $d: A \rightarrow \Omega_{A/k}$ denote the canonical derivation of $A$ over $k$ and let $d': B \rightarrow \Omega_{B/R}$ be the canonical derivation of $B$ over $R$. It is clear to me that the induced map,
\begin{align}
\Omega_{A/k} &\longrightarrow \Omega_{B/R} \\
fdg &\longmapsto \psi(f) d'\psi(g)
\end{align}
is surjective. The claim I am having trouble proving is that the kernel of this map is generated by terms $da$ with $\psi(a) \in \tau'(R)$. Questions have been asked about this before, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584811/determine-the-kernel-of-a-surjective-morphism-of-differential-modules), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886597/question-about-kahler-differentials-concerning-the-proof-of-lemma-130-6-commalg), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541319/kernel-of-the-induced-map-bar-phi-omega-s-r-to-omega-s-r?rq=1) for example. In the first, an answer is given in terms of the functor of points, which is fine, but I would really like to be able to do this via a diagram chase. The other two questions refer to the same problem, but I still haven't been able to see how a diagram chase concludes this. Is someone able to spell it out to me?

Suppose we had $fdg \mapsto \psi(f) d' \psi(g)$. I'm really not sure what we can conclude about $f$ or $g$ here. The answerer in the third question I linked above claims that we can conclude that either $\psi(f)$ or $\psi(g)$ must be zero, but I see no reason why this must be the case. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it by diagram chase, use the diagram they give in the proof of lemma 10.130.6 of http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM (I am too lazy to reproduce it) (be careful, I use the notation there not yours)

Call the left vertical map $k$ et $j$ the right one, and $b$ the upper horizontal map and $a$ the lower one. To simplify the notations, we suppose $R\subset S$ and $R'\subset S'$. This does not change the proof.

**Case 1** We suppose the map $R\to R'$ surjective.

By hypothesis, the vertical maps $k$ and $j$ are surjective, which will allow basic diagram chasing.

If an element $\alpha$ goes to zero through the induced map $\psi$
\begin{align}
\Omega_{S/R} &\longrightarrow \Omega_{S'/R'} \\
fdg &\longmapsto \phi(f) d'\phi(g)
\end{align}
let us call $\beta$ one of its antecedent in $\bigoplus S[a]$. Then the image of $j(\beta)$ in $\Omega_{S'/R'}$ being zero, there exists $$\gamma\in\bigoplus S'[(a', b')]
\oplus
\bigoplus S'[(f', g')]
\oplus
\bigoplus S'[r']$$ with $b(\gamma)=j(\beta)$. Let $$\delta\in\bigoplus S[(a, b)]
\oplus
\bigoplus S[(f, g)]
\oplus
\bigoplus S[r]$$ such that $k(\delta)=\gamma$. Then $$j(\beta)=b(k(\delta))=j(a(\delta))$$
Therefore, $j(\beta-a(\delta))=0$, with $\beta-a(\delta)\in\bigoplus S[a]$. Since the domain and codomain of $j$ are free module over respectively $S$ and $S'$ the only way for its image by $j$ to be zero is that each of its components of the type $s[g]$ ($s, g\in S$) is sent to zero, which means that 
$\phi(s)[\phi(g)]$ is zero in $S'[\phi(g)]$. Once again because this is a free module, we have necessarily $\phi(s)=0$ or $\phi(g)=0$, and so $s\in I$ or $g\in I$.

You conclude by saying that $\beta$ is a sum an element that goes to zero by quotienting in $\Omega_{S/R}$ and elements of the form $s[g]$ with $s$ or $g$ in $I$ therefore $\alpha$ is a sum of elements of the type $s\ dg$, with $s\in I$ or $g\in I$. Then you use the little trick given in the text to reach the following conclusion: the kernel of $\psi$ is $S\ dI$ (which is a smaller set of generators than $S\ d\phi^{-1}(R')$ because we are in case 1)

**Case 2** The general case

To be able to do diagram chasing, we have to change the domain of the map $k$. We call $R''=\phi^{-1}(R')$. Then the new left hand bottom corner of the diagram is 
$$\bigoplus S[(a, b)]
\oplus
\bigoplus S[(f, g)]
\oplus
\bigoplus_{r\in R''} S[r]$$
With this new domain, the map $k$ is surjective, and all the reasoning of case 1 applies, except at the end where $\beta$ is the sum of an element that goes to zero in $\Omega_{S/R}$ (that belongs to the original domain of $k$), an element that belongs to $\oplus_{r\in R''-R}S[r]$, and elements of the form $s[g]$ with $s\in I$ or $g\in I$. Therefore $\alpha$ is a sum of elements of the type $s\ dg$, with $s\in I$ or $g\in I$ like before, and a sum of elements of the type $s\ dr$ where $r\in R''-R$.

Therefore, the kernel of $\psi$ is indeed $S\ d\phi^{-1}(R')$ in the general case.